# Azure ExecuteBatch - how to set prefer-no-content header in c#?

Tags: c#, azure, batch-processing

Is there any way to set "prefer-no-content" header for Azure batch request?

```
 TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();

 foreach (var item in records)
 {
     batchOperation.Insert(item);
 }

 await _shortTable.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchOperation);
```

The only way I found is to set it directly in web request (webclient or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`TableBatchOperation.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn567049.aspx) accepts a boolean parameter indicating if the content should be echoed back. Try passing false there.

Comment: Damn. So simple. I don't know how I missed that. Thanks.